# Set default properties for ASP.Net controls

Tags: asp.net, properties, default-value, servercontrols

How would I set the default properties of server controls that I'll always use?
For example I have combos all over my pages which almost always look the same in the mark up text (e.g. CSS CLasses for PopUp, TextBox, Button, etc.)

I thought of putting the control inside an user control and set the properties there.
But then I would have to access the control itself with a property of the UC.

I want to get rid of these repeating tags:

```
        <Appearance>
            <AnyRecordFieldCell CssClass="SFGridAnyRecord"></AnyRecordFieldCell>
            <AlternateRecordFieldCell CssClass="SFGridAlternateRecord"></AlternateRecordFieldCell>
            <RecordPreviewCell CssClass="SFGridRecordPreview" />
            <GroupIndentCell CssClass="SFGridGroupIndentCell" />
            <GroupCaptionCell CssClass="SFGridGroupCaption" />
            <AnySummaryCell CssClass="SFGridAnySummary" />
            <GroupCaptionPlusMinusCell CssClass="SFGridPlusMinus" />
            <TopLeftHeaderCell CssClass="SFGridTopLeftHeaderCell" />
            <RowHeaderCell CssClass="SFGridRowHeaders" />
            <ColumnHeaderCell CssClass="SFGridColumnHeaders" />
            <GroupHeaderRowHeaderCell CssClass="SFGridGroupedColumnHeaders" />
            <FilterBarCell CssClass="SFGridFilterBarCell" />
        </Appearance>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Apart from styling-related properties what else needs setting?

Comment: Hi Joe, setting the CSS classes would already help a lot and reduce the markup code. See my edit in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ASP.NET Themes, you can use them to set mark-up for controls.

Comment: Hi, I'm using themes already. The thing is the control needs the info which classes to use. And this info is what I carry around in EVERY grid (see main post edit).

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a purely CSS solution if these elements are almost always the same - i.e. have styles for input and button elements.

Where styles differ the enclosing div, for example, can be referenced to change the style.

Comment: Hi, the thing is: I have to set the CSS classes so that control uses my own. I have themes for the controls already set up.

Comment: The elements you are talking about - input, button - can be referenced in the CSS. You don't need to set the class property on the control itself.